# How to add Font Awesome to Next.js project

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, next.js, font-awesome

I'm trying to add font-awesome to my Next.js project using webpack. I've tried following various instructions I've found on the web (using file-loader, url-loader), but nothing has worked for me. I gave up loading font-awesome with webpack for the moment, but I want to know how I can accomplish this. Currently, I have a `.scss` file that I use to load font-awesome.

Its contents:

```
$fa-font-path: "static/fonts";
@import "~font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss";
```

And I'm manually moving the fonts from `node_modules/font-awesome/fonts` to `static/fonts`. This works perfectly, But I wanted to know if there's a webpack 2 way to do it in 2017.

Answer (score 21):

### UPDATE

to set up this in `nextjs13` refer to:

[How to add Font Awesome to Next.js 13 project error Module not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76352403/how-to-add-font-awesome-to-next-js-13-project-error-module-not-found/76352510#76352510)

There are 3 ways:

### 1: By Adding a FontAwesome Script to the `Head` Component

Create `Head` component, add script and render this component either in `Header` component or in `Layout` file where you use it in every page.

```js
<Head>
  <script
    // you might need to get a newer version
    src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/fbadad80a0.js"
    crossOrigin="anonymous"
  ></script>
</Head>
```

### 2: Adding a link to the CDN within the `_document.js`.

It's possible to overwrite the root `html` file in Next.js by creating a `_document.js` under the `pages` folder. You could also add some other CDN as well. But, the easiest way is:

```js
<Html>
  <Head>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      type="text/css"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
    />
  </Head>
  <body>
    <Main />
    <NextScript />
  </body>
</Html>
```

### 3: Install All the Necessary `npm` Packages for FontAwesome

```
npm install --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons @fortawesome/react-fontawesome
```

And then at the top of the `_app.js` file add these lines:

```js
 // import Font Awesome CSS
import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core/styles.css";
import { config } from "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core";
config.autoAddCss = false;
```

Thereafter, you can import & use the rest of the FontAwesome icons as React Components like so:

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import { faCheck, faTrash } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";

<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCheck} className="fas fa-check" style={{ color: "red" }}
></FontAwesomeIcon>
```

Comment: A heads up for everyone reading this answer, the 3rd method throws a "`@fontawesome/fontawesome-svg-core/styles.css` module not found" error. Haven't verified the other methods though.

Comment: Method 3 works just fine. Using it right now in my project. Thanks @Yilmaz.

Comment: @Jarmos you have a typo. Not `@fontawesome`, it is  `"@fortawesome`

Comment: Thank you! But please move the newer update to the top. I completed everything just to see that it's not for next js 13.

Answer (score 12):

None of the solutions in this post are regarding how to use font-awesome via cdn, So, i am going to do just that.

There are multiple ways of doing it, but i normally use either _app.js or _document.js for such tasks.

Here is how it did it via _document.js

```js
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from "next/document";

class MyDocument extends Document {
    render() {
        return (
            <Html>
                <Head>
                    <link
                        href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
                        rel="stylesheet"
                        integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1"
                        crossOrigin="anonymous"
                    />
                    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/e20sdfsd9.js" crossOrigin="anonymous"></script>
                </Head>
                <body>
                    <Main />
                    <NextScript />
                </body>
            </Html>
        );
    }
}

export default MyDocument;
```

Here i simply added a link to css cdn of fontawesome in the DOM of next app which will be added in the pages rendered in browser.

to know more about _document.js please refer [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-document)

A similart approach can be followed via _app.js which i am not using right now, but in case anybody needs it, fell free to drop a comment and i will do it for you.

Here is a brief intro to [custom app or _app.js](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app)

Comment: Thanks. This was really helpful. However, this src link for Fontawesome seems not reachable anymore. It worked well after I changed the link into a link shown on https://cdnjs.com/libraries/font-awesome (*Do not use this link as src. Jump into the website and then get a link there)

Answer (score 11):

For anyone who'd like to see a real example with Next 9, check out https://github.com/UnlyEd/next-right-now

Interesting parts are:

- https://github.com/UnlyEd/next-right-now/blob/1f48e47a92/src/components/pageLayouts/Nav.tsx#L113 (usage)
- https://github.com/UnlyEd/next-right-now/blob/1f48e47a92/src/pages/_app.tsx#L22-L25 (config)

*Disclaimer: I'm a contributor to the project*

---

Config: pages/_app.tsx

```
import { config, library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';
import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core/styles.css';
import { faGithub } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons';
import { faAngleDown } from '@fortawesome/pro-solid-svg-icons';

// See https://github.com/FortAwesome/react-fontawesome#integrating-with-other-tools-and-frameworks
config.autoAddCss = false; // Tell Font Awesome to skip adding the CSS automatically since it's being imported above
library.add(
  faGithub, faAngleDown
);
```

> You can use solid/light/etc by importing the icon from the right repository

Usage: components/Nav.tsx

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';

<FontAwesomeIcon icon={['fab', 'github']} />
```

---

**Edit Next.js 10**:

While the above still works, what I recommend now for Next.js 10 and higher is to split your Font-Awesome related config into a different file, and import that file in `_app.tsx`. This makes the code more maintainable, that's all.

Something like:

- https://github.com/UnlyEd/next-right-now/blob/e6f6258207/src/pages/_app.tsx#L15
- https://github.com/UnlyEd/next-right-now/blob/e6f625820726d24967b4b14a5f32c93266fac3c9/src/utils/icons/font-awesome.ts

Comment: This solution is the one you are looking for

Comment: Note that the current answer is still compatible with Next.js 10, but I found a more maintainable way that is only compatible with Next.js 10+, which is basically to move all font-awesome related stuff to a different file, and import that file in `_app.tsx`. Like it's done there: https://github.com/UnlyEd/next-right-now/blob/e6f6258207/src/pages/_app.tsx#L15 and https://github.com/UnlyEd/next-right-now/blob/e6f625820726d24967b4b14a5f32c93266fac3c9/src/utils/icons/font-awesome.ts

Answer (score 5):

See here for the official documentation of **[Integrating with other tools and frameworks](https://github.com/FortAwesome/react-fontawesome#nextjs)**.

You'll be able to do the following:

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { config, library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';
import { fas } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { fab } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons';

config.autoAddCss = false;
library.add(fas, fab);

return ( 
  <FontAwesomeIcon icon={['fas', 'hat-wizard']} />
  <FontAwesomeIcon icon={['fab', 'github']} />
)
```

or

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faAdobe } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons/faAdobe';

return ( 
   <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faAdobe} />
)
```

Answer (score 4):

There are a few ways to do this. The first would be to create a head component via next/head and import there - see [here:](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/#populating-head)

Another way is to create a HOC to wrap your pages with and import there with a simple `import 'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css'`

Or, you could just import it into one of your page's with the same kind of import. (I believe this will scope it to that particular page however. Double check me on that)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

1. yarn add @fortawesome/fontawesome-free
2. in _app.js

   ```
   import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/fontawesome';
   import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/solid';
   import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/regular';
   import '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/brands';
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to post an answer using React 18 Next.js 13 and bootstrap 5 with fontAwesome.

There is an error that pops up for me

```
Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.
```

In the console I get an error something like this

```
 Expected server HTML to contain a matching <li> in <div>
```

I fixed this by doing the useEffect trick everybody does with Next.js to make the fontAwesomeIcon render only when mounted

Here is an example component

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import classNames from 'classnames';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { Row, Col } from 'reactstrap';

const AboutUsProcess = ({ icon, iconText, color, title, description, image, lottie, inverse, children }) => {


  const [mounted, setMounted] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
      setMounted(true) // must be true to render FontAwesomeIcon
  }, [])
  
  
  return  (
    <Row className="flex-center">
      <Col md lg={5} xl={4} className={classNames('pl-lg-6', { 'order-md-2': inverse })}>
      </Col>
      <Col md lg={5} xl={4} className="mt-4 mt-md-0">
        <h5 className={`text-${color}`}>
          { mounted && (
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={icon} className="mr-2" />
            )}
            {iconText}
        </h5>
        <h3>{title}</h3>
        <p>{description}</p>
        {children}
      </Col>
    </Row>
  );
};


export default AboutUsProcess;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
const Hello = () => {

    return (
        <div>
            <Head>
                <title>New Title</title>
                <meta name="description" content="some description here" />
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" />
            </Head>

            <h1>Hello World <i class="far fa-laugh-beam"></i></h1>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Hello
```

**Do install the below packages before proceeding**

```
npm i --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core
npm install --save @fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons
npm install --save @fortawesome/react-fontawesome
```

Answer (score 0):

In Next13 with Turbo Feature you got to add the font-awesome files into a fonts folder in the "app" folder - then use an absolute path.

Dirty :) hope this will be fixed soon..