# Next.js Do not add <script> tags using next/head warning

Tags: next.js

So I have a Next.js project that I built with Tailwind CSS, and I also using font fontawesome, SO i decided to use it in the old fashion way, by implementing the CDN path into the project by a script tag on the api/index file as the following:

```
import Head from 'next/head';
import MyComponent from '../components/pages/MyComponent/MyComponent';
export default function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Pizza Restaurant</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Pizza restaurant - The best pizzas in the world" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
        <script src="https://kit-pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/js/pro.min.js" data-auto-fetch-svg></script>
      </Head>
      <MyComponent />
    </>
  );
}
```

It all works, but I get the following warning:

```
Do not add <script> tags using next/head (see <script> tag with src="https://kit-pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/js/pro.min.js"). Use next/script instead. 
See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-script-tags-in-head-component
```

So I replaced the  tag with Next.js  tag as the following:

```
import Head from 'next/head';
import Script from 'next/script';
import MyComponent from '../components/pages/MyComponent/MyComponent';

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Pizza Restaurant</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Pizza restaurant - The best pizzas in the world" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>
      <Script src="https://kit-pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/js/pro.min.js" />
      <MyComponent />
    </>
  );
}
```

The warning is gone with this code.... but the fontawsome stopped working...

Any idea why?

Comment: The docs suggest that there's a Script component in  `next/Script` . It suggest user to include third-party scripts onto `_app` direcory. [Link to docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/optimizing/scripts)

Comment: @M.G.SSUPUNTHAKA thanks, already tried it, still not working.

Comment: `<Script src="https://kit-pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v6.4.0/js/pro.min.js" strategy="lazyOnload" />`  may be this might help. it will alter the load time of the script So NextJs will load and execute the script after Initial HTML content is Rendered. [Links to docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/optimizing/scripts#strategy)

Comment: @M.G.SSUPUNTHAKA, nope, still now working :(

Comment: Found this answer Someone posted. Hope this might help to resolve the issue [Link to the Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71891065/15119646)

Comment: @M.G.SSUPUNTHAKA Thanks friend! First + Second solution don't work also. I think they have a bug with fontawesome. Third solution is the one I want to avoid, I want to load via CDN.